# Serve Flask Server Over HTTPS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, flask, https

I'm learning AWS and I'm currently trying to deploy a Flask API over HTTPS. I set up an EC2 instance running Apache. I've already set up SSL on the site using ELB, and I tried to deploy flask over HTTPS with the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ("server.crt", "server.key")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000,debug=True,ssl_context=context)
```

However, I don't think the site is even starting the Flask server properply, as even though everything loads and I receive a message that Flask is running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/, sending a simple GET request over the browser doesn't work as the request just never loads and it eventually times out. It's almost behaving as if there is no server running on port 5000.

On the other hand, when I ran this program over http instead of https, it worked perfectly fine. Can anyone help me out in terms of what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: If you have HTTPs set on your ELB, then you usually do not need HTTPS on the ec2 instances. The connection looks as follows: `client---https--->ELB---http---> EC2`.

Comment: So then how do I make a request to the endpoint? Is it just https://<ip>:5000>

Comment: Yes. You would use https://<dns-of-elb>. The ELB would terminate the HTTPS and forward the requests to your instance using HTTP. If it does not work, have to look at all the settings of your ALB, Listener and Target group.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution to the issue was **termination HTTPS** connections on the ELB. This way, the communication between ELB and EC2 instance can be conducted using HTTP which is simple and easier to manage on the instances.